# Going in production with Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

before going in production with Symfony 2 I noticed there are a lot of bundles that are loaded by the framework in AppKernel.php. The defaults are:

```
$bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
    );
```

I use assetic, doctrine, twig, framework, monolog bundles. Can I safely remove the others so that the speed of loading will raise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely remove the SwiftmailerBundle.

The other ones (SecurityBundle, SensioFrameworkExtraBundle, JMSSecurityExtraBundle) may be harder as they have relations and your bundles may also have dependencies.

I would go ahead and just remove one bundle, run my tests (or manually test, if you don't have some) and see what's happening. If everything works, you can remove the next one.

Make sure to delete the cache after each removal (just to be safe).

Comment: what tests should I do? Simply load pages and see if it works?

Comment: Of course it would be best if you got functional tests/integration tests which automatically test each page. If you don't got some, I would simply click through the application, keeping an eye on the log. If you remove a bundle which is needed, you should recognize it by errors popping up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to remove these bundles as i don't think the speed of loading is effected a lot. The reason is because Symfony2 use Dependency Injection, so a class is only initialised when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

i would not remove anything if  i were you

if you want to work on a minimal basis, try using the [symfony2 components](http://symfony.com/components) as you need them
there is also a nice post by Fabien, the main coder of symfony, on [how you can build your own custom framework](http://fabien.potencier.org/), maybe you want to go that path, if you put a lot of value on minimalism and optimized code